# Query git reflog for all commits to a specific file

Tags: git, reflog

Is it possible to check the git reflog for all commits to a specific file.

I made a commit to file foo.txt and now it no longer shows in the git history via

```
git log foo.txt
```

I want to search the reflog to find all commits to this file so I can find my "lost" commit.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try:

```
git rev-list --all -- foo.txt
```

This will give you a list of all commits containing foo.txt.

Comment: I had to add an extra `--`, like so:  

    git rev-list --all -- foo.txt

Comment: I used: `git rev-list --all -- foo.html | xargs git show --name-status --oneline`

Comment: This does not search the reflog

Comment: this won't actually find lost commits, see my answer below

Answer (score 80):

Came across this while searching for an answer, which is simple: `git reflog -- $PATH`, which will include amends and other actions that will not be visible otherwise (though beware, reflog will be pruned by gc)

Comment: Wow -- so the rev-list didn't find my file, but reflog had it! Even had rev-list with `--all` but that still didn't find it. Thanks you just saved me a few hours.

Comment: to avoid confusion, it might be more proper to use the form `git reflog -- <path>` the double dash explicitly denotes you're passing it a file rather than a potential reference

Comment: This should clearly be the accepted answer. Especially since the OP does mention reflog.

Comment: One answer to rule them all, one answer to find them, One answer to bring them all and in the darkness cherry-pick them. @ArnaudP is right, this answer should be the accepted one, thanks so much!

Comment: This is definitely the most useful command, also the most recent one as well. Helped me to get the changes back which I lost :)

Comment: Would like to add, that if you have no idea what that path could have been, you can do `git reflog -- **/FILENAME` to get all commits where the file showed up (helped me on git version 2.21.0.windows.1)

Answer (score 21):

I'd use:

```
git rev-list --all --remotes --pretty=oneline -- foo.txt
```

The `--remotes` option lets you also use your remotes, and the `--pretty=oneline` makes it display the commit message. It is very useful when you're looking for a modification pushed to remote in a branch you don't know the name of.

Comment: I had to use `git rev-list --all --remotes --pretty=oneline -- foo.txt` (notice the `--`)

Comment: While this answers your own use case, `rev-list` doesn't search "the reflog", and won't find commits that are "lost", e.g. due to a reset of a branch.

Answer (score 4):

I lost a change when I was cleaning up my history with rebase.  I used something like this to search the reflogs:

```
for r in $(git reflog -- ${file} | cut -d ' ' -f1); do git show ${r}:${file}; done
```